# Syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell

In my bash script I am trying floating point comparison e.g.

```
a=0.32
b=0.38
```

I have written below snippet,

```
if [[ $(`bc-l <<< "$b > $a"`) -eq 0 ]]; then
echo "true"
else
echo "false"
fi
```

Please advice.

Comment: Pick one: `$(...)` or backquotes. They do the same thing, and should not be nested.

Comment: @chepner: I agree they *shouldn't*, but I don't think nesting them causes any problems.

Comment: It does if the backquoted command isn't itself generating a valid command.

Comment: Try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are actually running in bash shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=0.32; b=0.18; c=0.60    
if [[ $(bc -l <<< "$a > $b") -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "$a > $b"
else
    echo "$a <= $b"
fi

if [[ $(bc -l <<< "$a > $c") -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "$a > $c"
else
    echo "$a <= $c"
fi
```

Comment: `[[ "$a" > "$c" ]]` is not at all the same as `bc -l <<<"$a > $c"`. Try comparing `9` to `10`: The former will say that `9` is the larger number, because it's doing an **ASCII** comparison, not a **numeric** comparison. Observe output of `a=9; b=10; [[ $a > $b ]] && echo "$a is larger than $b"`.

Comment: (...aside: You don't need quotes in `[[ ]]`, which suppresses string-splitting and glob expansion implicitly, except on the right-hand side of `=` or `=~` operators when wanting those right-hand sides to be treated as literal strings rather than glob-style pattern or ERE-syntax regex respectively).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, How about a numerical context: `a=9; b=10; (( $a > $b )) && echo "$a is larger than $b" `? Would that be ok?

Comment: The problem with using a `(( ))`-style math context is that in bash it only supports integers, and we've got floating-point math in the question at hand. It'd be fine in ksh93, though, or with the `9` and `10` examples I used. BTW, this is also the subject of [BashFAQ #22](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022).

Comment: Yes. `(( ))` fails on reals.

Comment: I will remove my solution. I think bc is better for float comparisons. You caught it very nicely. Otherwise, scores of peopel would have been copying off my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding `set -x` to your script to show what it's doing will help:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

a=0.32
b=0.38

if [[ $(`bc-l <<< "$b > $a"`) -eq 0 ]]; then
echo "true"
else
echo "false"
fi
```

Output:

```
+ a=0.32
+ b=0.38
+++ bc-l
./39599898.sh: line 8: bc-l: command not found
+ [[ '' -eq 0 ]]
+ echo true
true
```

You probably meant `bc -l`, not `bc-l`:

```
+ a=0.32
+ b=0.38
+++ bc -l
++ 1
./39599898.sh: line 8: 1: command not found
+ [[ '' -eq 0 ]]
+ echo true
true
```

That's more like it.  Now it looks like you just wanted to compare the `1` that's output of `bc`, not run it as a command:

```
if [[ $(bc -l <<< "$b > $a") -eq 0 ]]; then
echo "true"
else
echo "false"
fi
```

```
+ a=0.32
+ b=0.38
++ bc -l
+ [[ 1 -eq 0 ]]
+ echo false
false
```

You can simplify further, given that the output you seek is boolean so comparing against 0 is just:

```
if ! let $(bc -l <<< "$b > $a"); then
echo "true"
else
echo "false"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax errors in your script.

- `$()` or back ticks are used for command substitution, not both.

You can correct it as,

```
if [[ $(bc -l <<< "$b > $a") -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

Comment: tried this on console, but shows true for both a > b & b > a

Comment: Perhaps the OP was trying to use  `<<<`, which is preferred to `echo | ` in bash.

Comment: @Rock The only error you had is using both `$()` and backticks

Comment: @TomFenech Corrected in answer.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R getting bash: bc: command not found error with above syntax